# Liquibase optimize changelog problem with integrity (ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

After some time I would like to optimize `changelog` I use in my `Spring-Boot` application. I use `SQL` syntax in my liquibase files.

I have updated some of the old sqls (without changing changeset name). And now I got:

```
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
         37 change sets check sum
              classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.sql::4::siewer was: 8:8560502cf93e550076df8a7dc82a45b6 but is now: 8:543d80fbaa5a5b468e56ac6ef4705e58
```

Is it possible to change old `changesets` and update `hashes` without executing the migration? I would like already in-use databases to work without changes (but to be able to get new migrations). At this moment when I start an application with fresh database everything is ok, but when I want to run app on already populated database I got errors.

Any tips? Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your migration scripts against a clear database, copy the hashes (or copy it directly from the error log one by one), and update the hash directly in the liquibase table. Just make sure it's updated together with the deployment of the new changesets, otherwise the app won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `<validCheckSum>` for it. This will tell liquibase what the checksum for this changeSet actually is.

So:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <validCheckSum>your_checksum_here</validCheckSum>
    <!-- changeSet logic here -->
</changeSet>
```

Or if you don't care about the checksum of the changeSet at all, you can use `ANY` instead of actual checksum:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
    <!-- changeSet logic here -->
</changeSet>
```

And some philosophy about it:

You shouldn't alter the existing changeSets. If you need to make the changes to your database schema, then you should write **new** changeSets in addition to the old ones.